# Selecting the first index after a certain timestamp with a pandas TimeSeries

Tags: python, pandas, lazy-evaluation

This is a two-part question, with an immediate question and a more general one.

I have a pandas TimeSeries, ts.
To know the first value after a certain time. I can do this,

```
ts.ix[ts[datetime(2012,1,1,15,0,0):].first_valid_index()]
```

a) Is there a better, less clunky way to do it?

b) Coming from C, I have a certain phobia when dealing with these somewhat opaque, possibly mutable but generally not, possibly lazy but not always types. So to be clear, when I do

```
ts[datetime(2012,1,1,15,0,0):].first_valid_index()
```

ts[datetime(2012,1,1,15,0,0):] is a pandas.TimeSeries object right? And I could possibly mutate it.

Does it mean that whenever I take a slice, there's a copy of ts being allocated in memory? Does it mean that this innocuous line of code could actually trigger the copy of a gigabyte of TimeSeries just to get an index value?

Or perhaps they magically share memory and a lazy copy is done if one of the object is mutated for instance? But then, how do you know which specific operations trigger a copy? Maybe not slicing but how about renaming columns? It doesn't seem to say so in the documentation. Does that bother you? Should it bother me or should I just learn not to worry and catch problems with a profiler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some setup:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: from datetime import datetime
In [4]: dates = [datetime(2011, 1, 2), datetime(2011, 1, 5), datetime(2011, 1, 7), datetime(2011, 1, 8), datetime(2011, 1, 10), datetime(2011, 1, 12)]

In [5]: ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(6), index=dates)

In [6]: ts
Out[6]: 
2011-01-02   -0.412335
2011-01-05   -0.809092
2011-01-07   -0.442320
2011-01-08   -0.337281
2011-01-10    0.522765
2011-01-12    1.559876
```

Okay, now to answer your first question, a) yes, there are less clunky ways, depending on your intention. This is pretty simple:

```
In [9]: ts[datetime(2011, 1, 8):]
Out[9]: 
2011-01-08   -0.337281
2011-01-10    0.522765
2011-01-12    1.559876
```

This is a *slice* containing all the values after your chosen date. You can select just the first one, as you wanted, by:

```
In [10]: ts[datetime(2011, 1, 8):][0]
Out[10]: -0.33728079849770815
```

To your second question, (b) -- this type of indexing is a slice of the original, just as other numpy arrays. It is NOT a copy of the original. See this question, or many similar:
[Bug or feature: cloning a numpy array w/ slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555431/bug-or-feature-cloning-a-numpy-array-w-slicing)

To demonstrate, let's modify the slice:

```
In [21]: ts2 = ts[datetime(2011, 1, 8):]
In [23]: ts2[0] = 99
```

This changes the original timeseries object ts, since ts2 is a slice and not a copy.

```
In [24]: ts
Out[24]: 
2011-01-02    -0.412335
2011-01-05    -0.809092
2011-01-07    -0.442320
2011-01-08    99.000000
2011-01-10     0.522765
2011-01-12     1.559876
```

If you DO want a copy, you can (in general) use the copy method or, (in this case) use truncate:

```
In [25]: ts3 = ts.truncate(before='2011-01-08')

In [26]: ts3  
Out[26]: 
2011-01-08    99.000000
2011-01-10     0.522765
2011-01-12     1.559876
```

Changing this copy will not change the original.

```
In [27]: ts3[1] = 99

In [28]: ts3
Out[28]: 
2011-01-08    99.000000
2011-01-10    99.000000
2011-01-12     1.559876

In [29]: ts                #The january 10th value will be unchanged. 
Out[29]: 
2011-01-02    -0.412335
2011-01-05    -0.809092
2011-01-07    -0.442320
2011-01-08    99.000000
2011-01-10     0.522765
2011-01-12     1.559876
```

This example is straight out of "Python for Data Analysis" by Wes. Check it out. It's great.

Comment: by using your suggested command `ts[datetime(2011, 1, 8):]` on a different dataset, I get the error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @Andreuccio check your datetime import, it should be `from datetime import datetime`. Although my answer might need to updated if that's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Me not knowing pandas, a general answer:

You can overload anything in python, and they must have done that there. If you define a special method [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) on your class, it is called when you use `obj[key]` or `obj[start:stop]` (With just key as argument in the former case, with a special [`slice` object](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) in the latter). You can then return anything you want.

Here's an example to show how `__getitem__` works:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if isinstance(k, slice):
            return k.start + k.stop # properties of the slice object
        else:
            return k
```

This gives you:

```
>>> f = range.Foo()
>>> f[42]
42
>>> f[23:42]
65
```

I assume that in your example, the `__getitem__` method returns some special object, which contains the datetime objects plus a reference to the original `ts` object. That special object can then use that information to fetch the desired information later on, when the `first_valid_index` method or a similar one is called. (It does not even have to modify the original object, like your question suggested.)

*TL;DR:* Learn not to worry :-)

**Addition:** I got curious, so I implemented a minimal example of the behavior you described above myself:

```
class FilterableList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
        self.filter = FilterProxy(self)

class FilterProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __getitem__(self, sl):
        if isinstance(sl, slice):
            return Filter(self.parent, sl)

class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, sl):
        self.parent = parent
        self.sl = sl

    def eval(self):
        return [e for e in self.parent if self.sl.start <= e <= self.sl.stop]


>>> l = FilterableList([4,5,6,7])
>>> f = l.filter[6:10]
>>> f.eval()
[6, 7]
>>> l.append(8)
>>> f.eval()
[6, 7, 8]
```