# Python: Memory usage increments while reading TIFFArray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of "TIFFFiles", where each "TIFFFiles" contains a "TIFFArray" with 60 tiff images each with a size of 2776x2080 pixel. The images are read as numpy.memmap objects.
I want to access all intensities of the images (shape of imgs: (60,2776,2080)). I use the following code:

```
for i in xrange(18):

    #get instance of type TIFFArray from tiff_list
    tiffs = get_tiff_arrays(smp_ppx, type_subfile,tiff_list[i])

    #accessing all intensities from tiffs
    imgs = tiffs[:,:,:]
```

Even by overwriting "tiffs" and "imgs" in each iteration step my memory increments by 2.6GByte. How can I avoid that the data are copied in each iteration step? Is there any way that the memory of 2.6GByte can be reused?

Comment: `imgs = tiffs[:,:,:]` is not valid Python, is it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker if it's a 3D array, it's valid slicing. That copies the content of `tiffs` into `imgs`, instead of just the reference as would be with `imgs = tiffs`

Comment: If you do `del tiffs` and `del imgs` at the end of each iteration, does the memory usage improve?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano No I tried several things of this kind, e.g. del statements, but the memory usage doesn't decrease at all.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano: In standard Python, or with an extension like NumPy? I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I guess anything that support multidimensional lists/arrays have this syntax, so it works in Numpy. Standard Python has lists and tuples that are 1D containers of other objects, so you can only slice them as `[:]`

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano: I've tagged the question accordingly. Otherwise, the numpy experts wouldn't know they are needed here :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: thanks. I didn't think about doing it and besides I don't have the right to do it

Comment: @user2042189 you better substitute `imgs = tiffs[:,:,:]` with `imgs = np.copy(tiffs)`  if you want to copy the content and not the reference of `tiffs` to `imgs`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555431/bug-or-feature-cloning-a-numpy-array-w-slicing)

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano Thank you I tried this out and my memory usage decreased for every loop by 600MB. However the memory still increments 2GByte in every loop...

Comment: @user2042189: I have the feeling that numpy has some big problems in handling and cleaning memory when reading files. I don't know if it's related to the underlying implementation or some misunderstanding with the garbage collector

Answer (score 0):

I know that is probably not an answer, but it might help anyway and was too long for a comment.

Some times ago I had a memory problem while reading large (>1Gb) ascii files with `numpy`: basically to read the file with `numpy.loadtxt`, the code was using the whole memory (8Gb) plus some swap.

From what I've understood, if you know in advance the size of the array to fill, you can allocate it and pass it to, e.g., `loadtxt`. This should prevent `numpy` to allocate temporary objects and it might be better memory-wise.

[`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html), or similar approaches, can help improving memory usage, but I've never used them.

**edit**

The problem with memory usage and release made me wonder when I was trying to solve my large file problem. Basically I had

```
def read_f(fname):
    arr = np.loadtxt(fname)  #this uses a lot of memory
    #do operations
    return something  
for f in ["verylargefile", "smallerfile", "evensmallerfile"]:
    result = read_f(f)
```

From the memory profiling I did, there was no memory release when returning `loadtxt` nor when returning `read_f` and calling it again with a smaller file.