# Python array assignments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment

I have a problem assigning values to variables in Python

```
import numpy
a = numpy.empty((3,3,))
a[:] = numpy.NaN
a
b=a
b[numpy.isnan(b)]=1
```

upto the second-to-last line a and b are equal to NaN arrays:

```
>>> a
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>> b
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

but when the last statement is executed (i.e. b[numpy.isnan(b)]=1) both a and b become arrays of ones

```
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

how can I set array b to ones and array a to NaN. Note that I need to maintain the b=a statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 b=numpy.copy(a)
```

Then `b[numpy.isnan(b)]=1`

```
In [45]: a[:] = numpy.NaN

In [46]: b=numpy.copy(a)

In [47]: b[numpy.isnan(b)]=1

In [48]: a
Out[48]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [49]: b
Out[49]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Using `b =a[:]` will NOT work in your example the values will change if you alter either array.

```
In [102]: import numpy

In [103]: a = numpy.empty((3,3,))

In [104]: a[:] = numpy.NaN

In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [106]: b=a[:]

In [107]: b
Out[107]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [108]: b[numpy.isnan(b)]=1

In [109]: a
Out[109]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [110]: b
Out[110]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
In [111]: a[:] = numpy.NaN

In [112]: a
Out[112]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [113]: b
Out[113]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is that objects in python are pass by reference meaning that when you *think* you've copied it, it's really just a *shadow* of the original and any changes get reflected back.

You need to use `numpy.copy()` The pythonic way to clone an array is by slicing:

```
b = a[:]
```

But that doesn't work for `numpy.ndarray`s because they have different behaviour. Slicing does not create a copy therefore you must use:

```
b = numpy.copy(a)
```

See:

[Bug or feature: cloning a numpy array w/ slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555431/bug-or-feature-cloning-a-numpy-array-w-slicing)

Proof:

```
>>> def setOnes(nparr):
...     nparr[:] = 1
...
>>> a = numpy.empty((3,3,))
>>> a[:] = numpy.NaN
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>> setOnes(a)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> a[:] = numpy.NaN
>>> a
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>> b = numpy.copy(a)
>>> b
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>> setOnes(b)
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> a
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes it doesn't work :/ Edited so it now makes sense.

Comment: Yes I know it does not ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham now it does

Answer (score 0):

look into the copy module.  I think deepcopy is what you want.

Alternatively, instead of b=a, you can write  b=a[:].

Answer (score 0):

`b = a` copies `a` reference into `b` and not `a` referenced object contents.

Try with:

```
b = numpy.array(a)
```